# Billing for this application is managed from the Google Cloud Console?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an App-engine server. I understand that I can set daily limits as "Maximum Daily Budget". But for my server, when I try to go set the daily limit, it simply says `Billing for this application is managed from the Google Cloud Console`. Does that mean I cannot set the daily limit? Does anyone know how I might still set the daily limit? Or does Google understand this as an `open` daily limit in the sense of carte blanche?

I indeed entered my credit card information through the `Cloud Console` but I didn't image this would prevent me from being able to set a daily limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a premier account, you can set a daily budget

> Note: Premier accounts do not use daily budgets, relying instead on monthly billing and pay-per-use.

[image]

Comment: Actually the image you have is what never showed up for me. It took about 12hrs for it to appear. All I got was the first line about `Billing for this application is managed from the Google Cloud Console`. But Now it is there. I don't know why it took so long.

Comment: The only option I have is the maximum daily budget, but when I try to set it, it just errors out.